# Move mouse to prevent PC from hibernate doesnt work with free pascal / lazarus

Tags: winapi, freepascal

I was looking for a solution to prevent a laptop with win7 from hibernate because any operation is done every some hours and I have no admin rights to change the energy saver menu. Anyway, I tried it with free pascal (Lazarus) like this:

```
procedure TForm1.Timer2StartTimer(Sender: TObject);
var MousePos: TPoint;

begin
    begin
     getCursorPos(MousePos);
     MousePos.x > 800 then Windows.SetCursorPos(10, 10); ;
     MousePos.X := (Mouse.CursorPos.x)+1 ;
     MousePos.Y := (Mouse.CursorPos.y)+1 ;
     Mouse.CursorPos := MousePos;
   end;
 end;
```

It makes the mouse move as expected and wanted, but the laptop still falls asleep. So I googled and found http://www.script-example.com/themen/Bildschirmschoner-verhindern.php. I used the application presented there and it worked. The laptop doesnt go to sleep although the application isnt doing anything else then me.

could anybody tell me how to manage that with free pascal? thanks a lot.

Comment: Are you using the TTimer.OnStartTimer event or the TTimer.OnTimer event? From the name of the function, it looks like you are using OnStartTimer which would be only executed only once and not regularly.

Comment: You could also change the machine's power policy settings and not have to worry about any programmatic work to prevent hibernation.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the Windows API function "SetThreadExecutionState" to reset the idle timer that Windows uses to decide when to show a screen saver or put the computer to sleep.

Use the following declarations to use the API:

```
const
  ES_SYSTEM_REQUIRED = DWORD($00000001);
  {$EXTERNALSYM ES_SYSTEM_REQUIRED}
  ES_DISPLAY_REQUIRED = DWORD($00000002);
  {$EXTERNALSYM ES_DISPLAY_REQUIRED}
  ES_USER_PRESENT = DWORD($00000004);
  {$EXTERNALSYM ES_USER_PRESENT}
  ES_CONTINUOUS = DWORD($80000000);
  {$EXTERNALSYM ES_CONTINUOUS}
  ES_AWAYMODE_REQUIRED = DWORD($00000040);
  {$EXTERNALSYM ES_AWAYMODE_REQUIRED}

type
  EXECUTION_STATE = DWORD;

function SetThreadExecutionState(esFlags: EXECUTION_STATE): EXECUTION_STATE; stdcall; external 'kernel32.dll';
```

Then use a TTimer set to an appropriate Interval value and in the OnTimer event, call

```
SetThreadExecutionState(ES_SYSTEM_REQUIRED);
```

For details on the background, see this documentation on MSDN: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa373233%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

This works on Lazarus 1.4.4 with FPC 2.6.4:

```
[...]

implementation

{$R *.lfm}

const
  ES_SYSTEM_REQUIRED = DWORD($00000001);
  {$EXTERNALSYM ES_SYSTEM_REQUIRED}
  ES_DISPLAY_REQUIRED = DWORD($00000002);
  {$EXTERNALSYM ES_DISPLAY_REQUIRED}
  ES_USER_PRESENT = DWORD($00000004);
  {$EXTERNALSYM ES_USER_PRESENT}
  ES_CONTINUOUS = DWORD($80000000);
  {$EXTERNALSYM ES_CONTINUOUS}
  ES_AWAYMODE_REQUIRED = DWORD($00000040);
  {$EXTERNALSYM ES_AWAYMODE_REQUIRED}

type
  EXECUTION_STATE = DWORD;

function SetThreadExecutionState(esFlags: EXECUTION_STATE): EXECUTION_STATE; stdcall; external 'kernel32.dll';

{ TForm1 }

procedure TForm1.Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
begin
  // Prevent Screensaver
  SetThreadExecutionState(ES_DISPLAY_REQUIRED);
  // Prevent Standby or Hibernate
  SetThreadExecutionState(ES_SYSTEM_REQUIRED);
end;
```

Comment: doesnt work at all. each single const makes the debugger stop. any solution by the mouse move I tryed?

Comment: This is code from Delphi. I don't have a lazarus available for testing. The SetThreadExecutionState() function is maybe already declared in one of the units delivered with Lazarus.

Comment: @Timmey83: A const cannot make the **debugger** stop. Do you mean the **compiler**?

Comment: @Timmey This is your answer. I'm sure you can deal with the compilation problems in your code. You can read the documentation too. The key is SetThreadExecutionState.

Comment: I have tested this with Lazarus now at home. The code compiles and runs as posted.

Comment: you did not make any changes and its compiling?

Comment: @ken white: sorry, I meant compiler.

Comment: I added more of the test code. This works on Lazarus 1.4.4 with FPC 2.6.4. But it should also work on much older versions. The compiler gives hints for some of the defined constants because they are not used, but no errors.

Comment: Exactly what i was looking for! Thank you. 
I use something like this....without timer.

SetThreadExecutionState(ES_CONTINUOUS OR ES_SYSTEM_REQUIRED OR ES_AWAYMODE_REQUIRED);
Application.ProcesMessages;
//Long execution time code
SetThreadExecutionState(ES_CONTINUOUS);